# corrupting xml file via transfering ftp

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, xml

I am transferring different xml files via ftp and it's working fine.

But one specific 90kb xml file getting corrupted during tranfer with ftp. Getting corrupted file with 6kb.

Any Help!

Comment: Corrupt h​o​w​?

Comment: @Ignacio that i don't know. Getting corrupted file after transferred  with ftp.

Comment: How do you know that it's corrupt if you can't tell how?

Comment: Before transferred it's shows text. After it's showing some binary and different characters.

Answer (score 2):

I was using sprint 3G card for net connection. I have changed settings of the card. I turned off bytemobile optimization. And it worked like a charm ! VOILA !